# possible to use wildcards?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to loop through all my NSUserDefaults and remove them the problem is there is a changing number of them.

Is there a way to do something like this

```
for (NSUserDefaults that key starts with "highScoreXXX") {

     *the XXX need to be wildcards*

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"key"];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSUserDefaults` has a method called `-dictionaryRepresentation` that you can use like so:

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDict = [[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
NSArray *keys = [[defaultsDict allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", @"highScore"]];

for(NSString *key in keys) {
   [[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```